# add list to gtk_tree_view in C

Tags: gtk, gtktreeview

folks,

im gonna tryin to make a little function which has something todo with the Gtk_tree_view that i've made,
the error response such as like this :

```
(main:8026): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_tree_view_get_model: assertion `GTK_IS_TREE_VIEW (tree_view)' failed

(main:8026): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_list_store_append: assertion `GTK_IS_LIST_STORE (list_store)' failed

(main:8026): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_list_store_set_valist: assertion `GTK_IS_LIST_STORE (list_store)' failed
^C
```

and the source, here you go :

```
 void addlist(bahan *unit, const gchar *str)
    {
        GtkListStore *store;
        GtkTreeIter iter; // penyambung store_append and store_set

        store = GTK_LIST_STORE(gtk_tree_view_get_model(GTK_TREE_VIEW(unit->treeview_aktifitas)));

        gtk_list_store_append(store, &iter); // need unary &, coz iter aint define like a pointer
        gtk_list_store_set(store, &iter, 1, str, -1);
    }
```

as you've figured , the structure of 'unit' was supposed like this :

```
  typedef struct
    {
        GtkWidget *window;
        GtkWidget *notebook;
        GtkWidget *start;
        GtkWidget *verbose;
        GtkWidget *settings;
        GtkWidget *about;
        GtkWidget *statusbar;
        GtkWidget *treeview_aktifitas;
        guint statusbar_id;
    } bahan;
```

and connected by this :

```
  unit->treeview_aktifitas = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(main,"treeview1"));
```

in the real case, im using 'glade 3', and have two columns on glade file, how to set on gtk_list_store_set ?

very appreciate any further help :)

Comment: Maybe it will be helpfull for you - http://scentric.net/tutorial/treeview-tutorial.html (gtk+ treeview tutorial)

Comment: thx for the effort which supposed to make me afford...

Comment: Posting the glade file might be useful. Where do you set the model for the treeview?

Answer (score 2):

well, i've found the fault now

```
    gtk_list_store_set(store, &iter, 1, str, -1);
```

just because my columns are two ,thus i need to

```
    gtk_list_store_set(store, &iter, 0,"aku", 1, "tes", -1);
```

which 0 represent first column and 1 represent next column, and so on -_-'